# Electron - Unable to use Js/Events/Jquery after loading Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, macos, electron

MainHtml:

```
    <head>
    </head>
    <header >
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="x1y1"></div> // Load contents dynamically here
        <script src="All scripts one by one"></script>
     </body>
```

Electron Window On load [Mainwindow already loaded the above html]

```
onload = $(function(){
     $('#ElementLoadedOnload').click()...etc tc;
     $('#ElementLoadedDynamicallyIn_x1y1_div').click()...etc tc;
});
```

So when electron loads the html , only the initial loaded html and elements are operable in jquery. When I load html dynamically using JQuery in x1y1 tag, the  `$('#ElementLoadedDynamicallyIn_x1y1_div').click()` does not work , so i have to include `onclick="FunctionName()"` for each element in html itself which works. Wht i am doing wrong here?... or is it possible in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the on method

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", '#ElementLoadedDynamicallyIn_x1y1_div' , function() {
    //Do what you want to do
});
```

Comment: Why is it so that , elements already loaded respond while, dynamic html do not? thats my main curiosity

Comment: On dynamic elements , the direct binding doesn't work so you need to add the on method to listen to all events

Comment: Is there a better way to do direct binding for dynamic elements via any Dom methods or JQ itself?

Comment: From my experience it is th best way to bind the events to elements dynamically . Also it is clean & understandable